# Django: My Register_Lost page not showing up

Tags: python, django

Still newbie in django, please help me

### **Urls.py :**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'lostfound'

urlpatterns = [

# /lostfound/
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

# /lostfound/lostitems
url(r'lostitems/', views.LostItemsView.as_view(), name='lost_items'),
```

this is the main problem of my url, i can't display my register_lost.html

```
# /lostfound/lostitems/addlostitems
url(r'/addlostitems/$', views.RegisterLostView.as_view(), name='register_lost'),`
```

### **Views.py :**

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Wallet

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
model = Wallet
template_name = 'lostfound/index.html'

class LostItemsView(generic.ListView):
model = Wallet
template_name = 'lostfound/lost_items.html'

class RegisterLostView(generic.ListView):
model = Wallet
template_name = 'lostfound/register_lost.html'
```

### **lost_items.html :**

```
 <div class="menu-button z-depth-3 right">
                                        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="{% url 'lostfound:register_lost' %}">
                                            <i class="medium material-icons right">playlist_add</i>Tambah Data
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
```

this is my register_lost.html that i want process

### **register_lost.html :**

```
{% extends 'lostfound/base.html' %}
{% extends 'lostfound/lost_items.html' %}
{% block title %}Register Lost Items{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% load staticfiles %}
    {% block sign_in %}
    {% endblock %}
     <h1>Hello</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: what would display in register_lost page?

Comment: have you specified block content in either of page you are extending?

Comment: the Hello text, but it didnt show up, i couldn't see any error though because the page always showing up the lost_items.html

Comment: @Gahan yes i already specified that, i just want to try my register_lost .html page, but it didn't show anything..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to switch lines in the `urlpatterns` list

this:

```
url(r'/addlostitems/$', views.RegisterLostView.as_view(), name='register_lost'),
```

before this:

```
url(r'lostitems/', views.LostItemsView.as_view(), name='lost_items'),
```

Comment: wow it's working, thanks a bunch, how can it works ? could you explain it a little ?

Comment: Django comparing urls to your patterns in a row one by one. And you have 2 regexps 'lostitems/' and '/addlostitems/$' and the first one is normaly matching  the 'addlostitems' url . So you need or switch them either change 'lostitems/' to '/lostitems/' for example.